# Is Static keyword in java used for memory management purpose ?

Tags: java

Because no matter how many objects will we create with static will share same reference ?

Comment: No. It is used to indicate lifecycle perhaps, but not for memory management. Java does not allow for explicit memory management.

Answer (score -1):

Yes static do use for memory management purpose in java.

Comment: No, it is `final` that means that.